# Graph API Search with React-native

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, search, react-native, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I try to get Events in Facebook with `GraphRequest` and `GraphRequestManager`, but my result is an [Error: type NSDictionary cannot be converted to NSString]

Here is my code:

```html
var search = JSON.parse('{ "q":"Coffee", "type": "event"}');
new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(new GraphRequest(
  search,
  null,
  function(error: ?Object, result: ?Object) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching data: ' , error);
    } else {
      console.log('Success fetching ddata: ' , result);
    }
  },
)).start()
```

Anyone helps me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ah. I sovled this. It's wrong parameter.
I found the constructor in `node-modules/react-native-fbsdk/js/FBGraphRequest.js`

Comment: That would be more helpful if you had posted an example as well :)